# Issue with Web3.js, try to call the contract to see the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js, truffle

I tried to make a call to the state of a contract developed on truffle, using web3.js in React, the problem is this, when I try to see the price of the token (already defined) it throws an error:

> Unhandled error: This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first

[image: Unhandled error: This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first]

This is the code of my App.js:

```
  const [AccountData, setAccountData] = useState({
    web3: 'undefined',
    account: '',
    balance: 0
  })

  const [Contracts, SetContracts] = useState({
    Token: '',
    Sale: ''
  })

  const PreLoad =async()=>{
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
      const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
      const netId = await web3.eth.net.getId()
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()

      if (typeof accounts[0] !== 'undefined') {
        const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0])
        setAccountData({ account: accounts[0], balance: web3.utils.fromWei(balance) })
      } else {
        window.alert('Please Login with MetaMask')
      }

      try{
        const Token = new web3.eth.Contract(SuperToken.abi, SuperToken.networks[netId.address])
        const Sale = new web3.eth.Contract(TokenSale.abi, TokenSale.networks[netId.address])
        SetContracts({Token, Sale})
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        alert('Error, see the console')
      }

    }
    else{
      alert('please install MetaMask or any provider!!')
    }
  }
  
  useEffect( () => {
    PreLoad()
  }, [])


  const BuyToken = async(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('Buying')
    let price = await Contracts.Sale.methods.tokenPrice().call()
    console.log(price)
  }
```

I think I'm following good the documentation from web3, and loading good the contracts on the useEffect, so I don't really know why this is happening.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message in text instead of pasting an image of it. Also, are you sure you have deployed the contracts?

Comment: "This contract object doesn't have address set yet" -- This error can also occur if the address you have assigned is incorrect; it doesn't exist, or you pasted in the txhash instead of the contract address.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> There was an error when I called the contract with web3js, this is the correct way:
>
> ```
> SuperToken.abi, SuperToken.networks[netId].address
> ```